# MyBatis include same <sql> fragment multiple times for joined tables of same type

Tags: mybatis

### Update 2016-06-07 - see my answer below for solution

Trying to find out if there is a way to reuse same  fragment in one query.

Consider this:

```
<sql id="personFields">
    per.id                  person_id,
    per.created_at          person_created_at,
    per.email_address       person_email_address,
    per.first_name          person_first_name,
    per.last_name           person_last_name,
    per.middle_name         person_middle_name
</sql>
```

The "per." alias is used to avoid column name clashing when using in queries with muiltiple joined tables.
It is included like this:

```
SELECT
<include refid="com.acme.data.mapper.PersonMapper.personFields"/>
FROM Person per
```

The problem is that it cannot be used more than once per query because we have the "per." alias.

Would be great to have something like this:

```
<sql id="personFields">
    #{alias}.id                  #{alias}_person_id,
    #{alias}.created_at          #{alias}_person_created_at,
    #{alias}.email_address       #{alias}_person_email_address,
    #{alias}.first_name          #{alias}_person_first_name,
    #{alias}.last_name           #{alias}_person_last_name,
    #{alias}.middle_name         #{alias}_person_middle_name
</sql>
```

And include it like this:

```
SELECT
<include refid="com.acme.data.mapper.PersonMapper.personFields" alias="per1"/>,
<include refid="com.acme.data.mapper.PersonMapper.personFields" alias="per2"/>
FROM Person per1
JOIN Person per2 ON per2.parent_id = per1.id
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is currently possible (not sure since what version):

**Define it:**

```xml
<sql id="AddressFields">
    ${alias}.id                 ${prefix}id,
    ${alias}.created_at         ${prefix}created_at,
    ${alias}.street_address     ${prefix}street_address,
    ${alias}.street_address_two ${prefix}street_address_two,
    ${alias}.city               ${prefix}city,
    ${alias}.country            ${prefix}country,
    ${alias}.region             ${prefix}region,
    ${alias}.sub_region         ${prefix}sub_region,
    ${alias}.postal_code        ${prefix}postal_code
</sql>
```

**Select it:**

```xml
<sql id="PurchaseSelect">
SELECT
purchase.*,
<include refid="foo.bar.mapper.entity.AddressMapper.AddressFields">
    <property name="alias" value="billing_address"/>
    <property name="prefix" value="billing_address_"/>
</include>,
<include refid="foo.bar.mapper.entity.AddressMapper.AddressFields">
    <property name="alias" value="shipping_address"/>
    <property name="prefix" value="shipping_address_"/>
</include>
FROM purchase
LEFT JOIN address billing_address ON purchase.billing_address_id = billing_address.id
LEFT JOIN address shipping_address ON purchase.shipping_address_id = shipping_address.id

</sql>
```

**Map it:**

```xml
<resultMap id="PurchaseResult" type="foo.bar.entity.sales.Purchase">    
    <id property="id" column="id"/>
    <!-- any other purchase fields -->
    <association property="billingAddress" columnPrefix="billing_address_" resultMap="foo.bar.mapper.entity.AddressMapper.AddressResult"/>
    <association property="shippingAddress" columnPrefix="shipping_address_" resultMap="foo.bar.mapper.entity.AddressMapper.AddressResult"/>    
</resultMap>
```

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately you can't do that, others have already tried (see some issues [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IBATIS-264) or [here](http://code.google.com/p/mybatis/issues/detail?id=652)). The includes are inlined and take no parameters.

One solution off the top of my head would be something like this:

```xml
<sql id="fragment">
  <foreach collection="list" separator="," item="alias">
    ${alias}.id                  ${alias}_person_id,
    ${alias}.created_at          ${alias}_person_created_at,
    ${alias}.email_address       ${alias}_person_email_address,
    ${alias}.first_name          ${alias}_person_first_name,
    ${alias}.last_name           ${alias}_person_last_name,
    ${alias}.middle_name         ${alias}_person_middle_name
  </foreach>
</sql>
```

include it just once like:

```xml
<select id="getPersons" parameterType="java.util.List" ... >
  SELECT
  <include refid="fragment"/>
  FROM Person per1
  JOIN Person per2 ON per2.parent_id = per1.id
</select>
```

and have a `parameterType="java.util.List"` sent from the mapper interface:

```java
public interface PersonMapper {
  public List<String> getPersons(List<String> aliases); 
  // called with aliases = ["per1", "per2"]
}
```

This is ugly because your (higher level) code will have to know the aliases used inside the (lower) queries and also uses string substitutions for the fragment (`${...}` instead of `#{...}`) which can be dangerous if not handled properly... but if you can live with that...

Comment: Thanks. Yeah this is ugly adds clutter and doesn't really solve the problem. I think just copy pasting the fragments will work for now.

Answer (score 3):

This feature is asked to be implemented for more than 2 years (https://code.google.com/p/mybatis/issues/detail?id=652).

This static parameters in include can be found implemented in this fork: https://github.com/kmoco2am/mybatis-3

It is fully working and it has the same syntax as standard configuration parameters or static variables:

```xml
<sql id="sometable">
  ${prefix}Table
</sql>

<select id="select" resultType="map">
    select 
        field1, field2, field3
    from
    <include refid="sometable">
        <placeholder name="prefix" value="Some"/>
    </include>
</select>
```

Hopefully, it will be soon accepted for the main source repository.