# How can I reuse an SQL fragment with parameters?

Tags: mybatis, ibatis

I'm intending to make a fragment for reusing with parameters.

```xml
<insert ...>
  <selectKey keyProperty="id" resultType="_long" order="BEFORE">
    <choose>
      <when test="_databaseId == 'derby'">
        VALUES NEXT VALUE FOR SOME_ID_SEQ
      </when>
      <otherwise>
        SELECT SOME_ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL FROM DUAL
      </otherwise>
    </choose>
  </selectKey>
  INSERT INTO ...
</insert>
```

Can I make an SQL fragment using parameters?

```xml
<sql id="selectKeyFromSequence">
  <selectKey keyProperty="id" resultType="_long" order="BEFORE">
    <choose>
      <when test="_databaseId == 'derby'">
        VALUES NEXT VALUE FOR #{sequenceName}
      </when>
      <otherwise>
        SELECT #{sequenceName}.NEXTVAL FROM DUAL
      </otherwise>
    </choose>
  </selectKey>
</sql>
```

So that I can reuse them like this?

```xml
<insert ...>
  <include refid="...selectKeyFromSequence"/> <!-- How can I pass a parameter? -->
  INSERT INTO ...
</insert>
```

Is this possible?

Comment: You can reuse sql fragments with parameters by using mybatis scripting http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25055276/reusing-dynamic-sql-fragments

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As of version 3.3.0 you can do it like this:

```
<sql id="myinclude">
  from ${myproperty}
</sql>

<include refid="myinclude">
  <property name="myproperty" value="tablename"/>
</include>
```

See section SQL in http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/sqlmap-xml.html

Answer (score 1):

You cannot pass parameter to  tags. There is a similar [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20914451/mybatis-include-same-sql-fragment-multiple-times-for-joined-tables-of-same-typ), [iBatis issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IBATIS-264) and a [MyBatis issue](https://code.google.com/p/mybatis/issues/detail?id=652).

> Includes are in-lined when the xmls are parsed so the do not exist as
>   their own once the startup process finishes (from MyBatis issue).

However, you can use variables inside  tags. You do not pass it as a parameter but you can give it as a parameter to the function that has the include tag. You need to use the *same* variable name in all functions, i.e. `#{sequenceName}`.